# Convert a raw pointer to a clone_ptr

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers, xerces

I have a clone_ptr implementation, as was shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078972/clone-ptr-problem-i-need-to-create-a-copy-object-using-a-function-of-the-library) question and I have a problem where I need to create a clone_ptr from a raw pointer returned from a function.

Here is the code:

```
DOMDocument* doc =  impl->createDocument(
                                                0,                   // root element namespace URI.
                                                XML::X(docname.c_str()),  // root element name
                                                0);                  // document type object (DTD).
        document.get() = *doc;  //No way to assign clone_ptr document to raw doc pointer
```

Where `document`& `impl` are declared as follows:

```
clone_ptr<DOMImplementation, default_clone<DOMImplementation> > impl; 
    clone_ptr<DOMDocument, default_clone<DOMDocument> > document;
```

The `createDocument` function above returns a raw `DOMDocument` pointer and is assigned to the local variable `doc`, now I want to get my document clone_ptr and actually pass it the raw pointer gotten from the create document function.  It seems however the compiler is not too happy with this as it says the following:

```
 error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'xercesc_3_1::DOMDocument' to 'clone_ptr<T,Cloner>::pointer'
        with
        [
            T=xercesc_3_1::DOMDocument,
            Cloner=default_clone<xercesc_3_1::DOMDocument>
        ]
```

So my question is how can I allow a raw pointer to be explicitly or implicitly converted to a `clone_ptr`?
EDIT:

Clone specialization:

```
template<typename T>
struct default_clone
{
    static T* clone(T* pPtr)
    {
        return pPtr ? pPtr->clone() : 0;
    }
};

template<>
struct default_clone<DOMDocument>
{
    static DOMDocument* clone(DOMDocument* pPtr)
    {
        DOMImplementation* impl = DOMImplementationRegistry::getDOMImplementation(XML::X("Core"));
        return pPtr ? impl->createDocument(0, XML::X(""), 0) : 0;
    }
};

template<>
struct default_clone<DOMImplementation>
{
    static DOMImplementation* clone(DOMImplementation* pPtr)
    {
        return pPtr ? DOMImplementationRegistry::getDOMImplementation(XML::X("Core")) : 0;
    }
};
```

Comment: I do no know if my answers to your previous two question regarding your clone-pointer where useful, but if they where, it would be nice if you accepted them.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: added a comment to the answer to my prev question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Giving your [`clone_ptr` implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078972/clone-ptr-problem-i-need-to-create-a-copy-object-using-a-function-of-the-library), and the fact that `doc` is a pointer, wouldn't it be `document.reset(doc)`?

Comment: that is true that it cannot be cloned, however I have a template<> default_clone<DOMDocument> struct which is a template specialization to copy the DOMDocument...

Comment: @Tony: Ah, then it's different from the implementation in the question you linked to. I have just added a hint saying you might want to specialize your `default_clone` rather than using a different one... `:)`

Comment: added what I meant with my clone specialization for DOMDocument and DOMImplementation...

Comment: @Tony: That makes my second paragraph unnecessary. I have removed it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the library but would be very surprised if document.get() returned an l-value (thus your assigning something to it seems rather strange). That doesn't mean it won't compile as very few people implement return types as const (ie. returning a constant as the temporary), just that the assign won't have the desired effect.